# Use React State in a hook with two separate exports

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

So i have created a hook which will act as a bridge between two different components.
So the second function will take the data that the first function calculates and display them, however the first function will actually return a count of the displayed data.

These need to be connected with a state, since they should also update on change, those data can be deleted in the second function.

So what i want to do is, i want to setState in the second function and read it out in the first one. The way i did it now it won't work, since the useState is outside of a component.

How can i use this useState in both of these functions?

```
const [state, setState] = useState<string[]>([]);

export const thisUsesState = () => {
   return countOfArrayState;
}

export const thisUpdatesStateReturnsComponent = () => {
   return <Component></Component>;
}
```

Comment: `useState` is scoped to a component. If you need ti share state across components, either have your state in your parent component and pass data as props, or use a Context or a state manager like redux

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent component for both the function and you can use state like a charm.

```
const Func: React.FC = () => {

const [state, setState] = useState<string[]>([]);

export const thisUsesState = () => {
   return countOfArrayState;
}

export const thisUpdatesStateReturnsComponent = () => {
   return <Component></Component>;
}
return something

}
export default Func
```